# A way to store information

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm making a Console Application using Visual Studio, the coding is being written in (C#). The program is going to be a basic Command Prompt game.

So, I'm trying to find a way to store information.. I'm fairly new to coding in general, so I don't know what type of file I will need to make. I just want a way to store things like names, and character levels, so essentially strings and integers.

Although, I don't want to use a ".txt" file or something like that. I'm really looking for something embed into the program.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question; I'm happy to answer any further questions you may have, so that I can achieve what I'm working toward.

Comment: check [Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=VS.90).aspx) files they are easily embedded into the program.

Comment: But you can't write to a resource once your program is compiled.

Comment: Yeah, I did look into using a resource file, but the problem is that they are only read only, I need something that I can almost constantly change info on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally missed Florians answer but I post this anyway since you might learn a few things from it even though it's essentially the same answer.

```
[Serializable]
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public Weapon Weapon { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Weapon
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MaxDamage { get; set; }
    public int Range { get; set; }
    public WeaponClass Class { get; set; }

    public enum WeaponClass { Sword, Club, Bow }
}
```

and then you can use these like this

```
var filename = @"c:\temp\player.xml";

var sword = new Weapon { Name = "Dáinsleif", MaxDamage = 42, Range = 1, Class = Weapon.WeaponClass.Sword };
var player = new Player { Name = "Fafhrd", Level = 19, Weapon = sword };

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Player));

var file = File.OpenWrite(filename);
ser.Serialize(file, player);
file.Close();

player = null;

file = File.OpenRead(filename);
player = (Player)ser.Deserialize(file);
file.Close();
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Player xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>Fafhrd</Name>
  <Level>19</Level>
  <Weapon>
    <Name>Dáinsleif</Name>
    <MaxDamage>42</MaxDamage>
    <Range>1</Range>
    <Class>Sword</Class>
  </Weapon>
</Player>
```

Comment: Thank you, this may be just what I needed. I'll try it out and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks and good luck! Eventually you will need to look into something more sophisticated than serialized XML. I recommend MongoDB, SQLite, or SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Comment: Cool. Also, how can I output the information stored in the xml file the next time I run the program?

Answer (score 2):

An easy and straightforward way would be to create a serializable class that stores all relevant data. This class can than be easily written to and read from e.g. a Xml file.

Sample code:

```
[Serializable]
public class GameData
{
    public int Highscore;

    /* Plus any other data you want to store */
}

public class Game
{
    private const string gameDataLocation = "C:\\GameData.xml";
    private GameData gameData;

    /* Your game methods */

    private void StoreData()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GameData));
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(gameDataLocation);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, gameData);
        writer.Close();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GameData));
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(gameDataLocation, FileMode.Open); 
        gameData = (GameData)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't tried it yet, though when reading through the code this looks like what I need.

Comment: With this how can I make it store user input? Something like a string; and then how do I get the information from the file and then turn it into a string?

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out how to call those methods.. They don't show up when I try to call them in my Main method.

Comment: Just add a string field to the GameData structure and fill it with any text you want.

Comment: Cool, so how do I call those methods? The StoreData and LoadData.

Comment: OK, it seems like you are really an absolute beginner. I assumed a good understanding of C# basics, sorry. Better forget about serialization and start with basic programming principles. As soon as you gained a good understanding of those basics it will be easy for you to adapt the example to your use-case.

Comment: Okay, sorry. I think I understand most of it, I just don't know how to call a private method.. Like I said above, it's not showing up when I try to call it in my Main method.

Comment: Sweet, I figured out how to call it.

Comment: Learning by doing :) Please consider to accept the answer that helped you most.

Comment: Alright. Anyway, I think I almost got this, I'm just not sure if it's actually writing the information to the file; because I'm not sure how to convert the xml files info into a string value.
Could that be done easily? Or is it anywhere close to getting a string from a ".txt" file?

Comment: You can just navigate to the path where the Xml file is stored (in the example C:\GameData.xml and open it in any text editor.

Comment: Okay, well it is empty after running my program.

Comment: Actually now all it says is: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GameData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:nil="true" />"

Comment: Thats OK, `xsi:nil="true"` means that the GameData reference you serialized was null. You have to instanciate a GameData instance and sets its members so that anything meaningful gets written to the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you first should think more deeply about what you want. txt is past, use [xml for separate levels, for characters](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813). Also runtime serialization [(storing objects in binary format)](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/Serialization-in-C.html) might help

Comment: I'll see if I can figure this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store game settings you may use app.config and autogenerated Settings class.
If you want to store best gamers names or something, it is reasonable to think about your own format

Comment: At this point I'm only trying to store the current gamers name, and level.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Sqlite database for this purpose.There you can also store binary serialized objects and it is pretty easy to work with it.

[Sqlite usage in c# example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SQLiteCSharp.aspx)

[Sqlite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html)

Comment: O RLY? This is your advice for someone who just starts programming and probably doesn't know what XML is?

Comment: I think it's easier to use a database instead of xml files,this is how i would do it.

Comment: Could someone show me, or send me a link of how to use a database? Since you say it's easier.

Comment: Well, i disagree. DB has more levels of abstractions(connections, relations, queries, OH MY GOD, do i need to continue?..)

Comment: So xml would be the way to go?

Comment: Well then, i think than James must try both the Database and the xml, and decide what is better for his needs. But i also must add that he stated he dosen't want to use .txt files and xml is also a text file.

Comment: Ye, i'd start with that. It has a lot of limitations comparing to database, but according to your needs, it's more than enough to use XML.

Comment: I totally agree, basic Xml serialization is pretty straightforward in .NET. Have a look at my answer for a basic example.

Comment: So with xml serialization, I can make a file from the users input, and read that file on the next run?

Comment: If this is what you want, then yes)

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to contain more than 1 player data, i'd recommend to use some well-structured storage, such as XML. Google thatm google LINQ to XML.

But! Better start with txt, get familiar with C#, classes, syntax, etc. Then learn to use functionality, essentially based on this. This will be hard to dive into abstractions based on somewhat you are not familiar with/

Comment: I've got a basic understanding right now. So I may look into xml, if it's somewhat understandable, maybe that means it's time for me to learn more :)